# How to add google API console created API Key for Firebase Cloud messaging

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, google-console-developer

How to add `google API console` created `API Key` for Firebase `Cloud messaging`. Currently, firebase has created API Key by default, but there is no option to add another key?

Answer (score 0):

You can generate a new FCM server key from the [Firebase console](https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project/_/settings/cloudmessaging/). But you can not add your own keys from other places to FCM.

Comment: Is there any option in firebase to create more than one keys, because I want to have different restrictions on different keys? Also if there is no such option then why there is option to even create an API key in Google API console when you just cannot even use them.